# MySQL queries hang; database down

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cpanel

I have one big dataset (1.6 GB) and I am writing MySQL queries to it. Some queries took long time (10 sec). After I send my app, that send this queries, to few people (cca 20) something went wrong and database is "corrupted" (don't know the better word). I cant send queries to this database anymore (query hang, process never ends).

I have tried to repair my database using "Repair database" in cpanel, but it returns:

> Internal Server Error
>
> 500
>
> No response from subprocess ( (cpanel)): The subprocess reported error
>   number 72,057,594,037,927,935 when it ended. The process dumped a core
>   file.

Do I have to delete database (supose I can, I didn't try), or is there any way to somehow restore (restart) database.

I am really not good at database management.

Comment: Do you use something like MySQL Workbench ? Can you make some query to get some info or nothing works?

Comment: Nothing works, I can't make any query

Answer (score 0):

in my case you just need to update your cpanel.
or you have duplicate cpanel

try

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/autorepair fix_duplicate_cpanel_rpms
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/upcp --force
```

Comment: I don't have autorepair file in scripts. Only aduser

Comment: I only have aduse files in scripts directory so can't execute: /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/upcp ?